# How to instruct libtool when building with conda to use conda installed packages instead of /usr/bin?

Tags: conda, miniconda, libtool

When building `libtool` with `miniconda3` (in the following called `conda`), it ends up using `ar`, `sed`, `grep`, and `dd` from `/usr/bin/` and not the respective packages installed by conda even though the `which` command returns the conda installed packages (and these also exist in the active conda environment's `bin` folder.

Installing the respective dependency packages `ar`, `sed`, etc., before `libtool`  and using `conda clean --all` before building the environment did not solve the issue.

Does anyone know how to instruct libtool to use the conda packages instead of those in `/usr/bin/`, avoiding editing manually the `conda/envs/my_env/bin/libtool` file?

EDIT:

Just saw that the [libtool configure notes](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Configure-notes.html) state that `libtool` prefers native tools:

*"On AIX, native tools are to be preferred over binutils; especially for C++ code, if using the AIX Toolbox GCC 4.0 and binutils, configure with AR=/usr/bin/ar LD=/usr/bin/ld NM='/usr/bin/nm -B'. "*

This configuration might be the explanation for the issue.

Comment: Maybe have a look at how Conda Forge does it ([`libtool` feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/libtool-feedstock/tree/main/recipe)). By using the Conda Forge `compilers` package, one gets many environment variables properly configured to preferably build/link against Conda packages. But the recipe further involves some patching (not sure if needed for you) and several environment variables set in the [`build.sh`](https://github.com/conda-forge/libtool-feedstock/blob/main/recipe/build.sh).